# Separate TAG and Branch Menu in SVN Team

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

[image]

I want separate branch and tag menu. i have another latest version of eclipse, in that this branch/tag menu shows separately.

Below is current installation details snapshot.
[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Branch or tag in Subversion is similar operation. Both of the operations create symlink-like copy, but the commits to /tags should not be usually allowed (it's a tag after all).

In any case, I guess that the other Eclipse that shows these Tag and Branch commands separately has [Subversive plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) instead of [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse).